# Windows Server 2019 RD Deployment Quick Start wont work

Tags: remote-desktop-services, windows-server-2019

I am attempting to install Remote Desktop Services on a Windows Server 2019 server using the Add Roles and Features Wizard. During installation, it fails with the following error message:

> The post installation configuration did not complete. Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Below is a screenshot of the error message. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Are there any pending reboots on the server? Have all the latest updates been installed? Is this a fresh install or an existing server running other role services?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it.

You have a problem with the FQDN, when you install the roles you must see entire FQDN (with the domain name). To solve this I deactivate all the adapters and only have active the adapter that have the communication with the domain (in my case is the same VLAN). I leave the domain and rejoin the machine to my domain.

I install the roles only with the adapter that has the communication with the DC and voila!

Answer (score 0):

In Add/Remove Features Wizard, it did not work when the server name did not show Fqdn. AKA SERVERNAME. Removed from domain, readded, and then in the wizard saw that it was SERVERNAME.DOMAIN.ORG    . Install then succeeded via wizard.